# Function if and round on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a function where, if my student's grade is greater than 6, the regular round function is applied, but, if the grade is 5.9 or below, it will round down.

For example if one student has 7.6, the function will make it 8 but if another student has 5.7, this will not be 6 but 5.

Comment: What have you tried and what doesn't Work? Show your code.

Answer (score -1):

`=if(grade>=6,round(grade,0),rounddown(grade,0))`